# Power iteration with rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

As I understand it, the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) is a method used to approximate the eigenvalue with the largest magnitude. It has a convergence rate $\frac{\lambda_{\max}}{\lambda_{\min}}$.

I am given the following question:

> Given that we have a matrix $n \times n$ with rank $1$, this implies that it has a single eigenvalue given by $u v^T$. If we want to apply the power iteration to that matrix, what eigenvector will it converge to and how many iterations are required for it to converge exactly to that eigenvector?

---

**My attempt**

Given that $A$ has rank $1$ and it has an eigenvalue $u v^T$
$\Rightarrow A$ has eigenvalues $= 0$ with multiplicity $(n-1)$ following $\mbox{rank}(A) = 1 \Rightarrow \mbox{null}(A) = n-1$
Then the power iteration will find eigenvector $u$ but what about its convergence rate? Is it infinity?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a typo. The matrix $A$ is $uv^\top$, but its nonzero eigenvalue is $v^\top u$, corresponding to the eigenvector $u$.

Note that the column space of $A$ is one-dimensional and spanned by $u$. So the power method finds the eigenvector in one step.